# compilation failed for package ‘raster’

Tags: r, compilation, raster

I have problems to compile the "raster" package.
I tried 
install.packages("raster", dependencies = TRUE)
with no success.
Any suggestions?
The main problem is:

```
g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/zfgbe/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c RasterModule.cpp -o RasterModule.o
In file included from RasterModule.cpp:2:
spat.h:158: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘crs’
spat.h:158: error: making ‘crs’ static
spat.h:158: error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type ‘std::string’
spat.h: In member function ‘std::string SpRaster::getCRS()’:
spat.h:200: error: ‘crs’ was not declared in this scope
spat.h: In member function ‘void SpRaster::setCRS(std::string)’:
spat.h:201: error: ‘crs’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [RasterModule.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘raster’
```

Comment: Have you looked at the package's Description file?

Comment: You mean this restrictions?:
LinkingTo: Rcpp
Imports: Rcpp, methods
SystemRequirements: C++11

But is this a problem?

Comment: The first line suggests to me that you do not have a properly installed g++ compiler. My first line during installation of raster which is the one that does RasterModule.o starts `g++ -std=gnu++11` and the Description file says you need C++11. Have you even installed Rcpp?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the depend on the rather new C++ Implementation (C++11).
The version 2.5-8 of raster does not have this dependency.
For me this installation command worked:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/raster/raster_2.5-8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```